# OSX 10.11 - how to open the chrome with flag --use-fake-device-for-media-stream?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, webrtc

I need to test Google Chrome with fake camera input for development testing. In OSX 10.11 how do you open Google Chrome with command line `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream`  ( http://www.webrtc.org/testing)
And check the camera list items from javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --use-fake-device-for-media-stream
```